# Определяемое слово в причастном обороте

Tags: определения

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(Тростенцова, Ладыженская. Русский язык. 7-й класс)

Разве ни в каком случаще определяемое причастным оборотом слово не может входить в его состав? И в особом слоге? И как художественный приём? И в поэзии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во всех шести примерах ошибочен *порядок слов* (зависимые слова оторваны от причастия), допустить такое нельзя и в художественных текстах, за исключением *пародийных*. В сбивчивой речи и изредка в поэзии (в интересах рифмы) встречаются похожие случаи перестановки, например (из песни):

> ...солдаты, с кровавых не пришедшие полей...